# Xamarin Forms Override the OnSizeAllocated method in view model

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am making use of Prism in my xamarin forms project.Currently I have overridden the OnSizeAllocated method in view class.How to implement OnSizeAllocated method in view model?In other words is it possible to override the OnSizeAllocated method in view model?

This is the piece of code that I want to implement:-

```
        private double width = 0;
        private double height = 0;
        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            try
            {
               if (App.vw_CurrentPage == "Bandwidth")
             {
                base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called
                if (this.width != width || this.height != height)
                {
                    this.width = width;
                    this.height = height;
                    double dEntryWidth = (width / 11) * 7;
                    double dEntryWidth1 = (width / 9) * 6;
                    double dGridHeight = height * 0.352;
                    txtBandwidthHotel.WidthRequest = dEntryWidth1;
                }
              }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `viewmodel` doesn't know anything about the `view` therefore how would it be able to call `onsizeallocated`. I would create an interface `IViewModelBase` and have a method called `OnSizeAllocated` that the view calls

Comment: Without knowing more about what your goal is, it's really quite difficult to give you proper advice on how to achieve your goal. However, I would emphasize that your ViewModel should never know anything about the View. Proper MVVM patterns keep the coupling very loose between View and ViewModel

Comment: Here is my goal...When device changes orientation, the OnSizeAllocated method fires.I want to change the dimensions(height and width) of some icons when the device changes orientation.I want the icons to appear in different sizes for landscape and portrait mode.@DanS.

Comment: Can u share some code on how to implement it using an interface?@user1